# Http Redirect and asp.net

Tags: content-delivery

I have implemented URL redirection in one of application in asp.net and Tridion. Whenever I add any new redirect URL, I have to restart the application pool to reflect the changes because I am maintaining these redirect URLs in a configuration file which is referenced in the web.config file through configSource attribute as below –

```
<httpRedirect configSource="HttpRedirect.config" />
```

Could anybody suggest me the way to get changes reflected immediately without restarting app pool?
Is there any way to get the app pool restarted automatically  after any new change in the HttpRedirect.config   file?

NOTE – I would not want to merge HttpRedirect.config  file in the web.config due to being too large list of URLs.